# Fading out on spriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm making a spriteKit game, and I am new to sprtieKit.
I want to make the screen fade out when the game is over, all the screen. For example, my screen is blue, when you lose the game I want it to slowly become black. Can it be done someway? 
Thanks In Advance (:

Comment: Are you going to present a new scene after everything faded out?

Comment: There are lots of coding tutorials out there. Try to take a look at these before opening a new thread for that. It might be that you get blocked from asking more questions when you only ask very simple ones. You could use UIView.animatewithDuration or just a SKTransition.

Comment: As i said, i'm new to spriteKit, i have tried to search google but i've found nothing... When you talk about 'simple' things like "UIview.animatedWithDuration", I have no idea what are you talking about... @Sam0711er

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to stay at the current scene after everything faded out. Add this line when game is over:

```
[self runAction:[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:2.0]];
```

The reverse action is `fadeInWithDuration` by the way.

If you're going to present a new scene after everything faded out. Present the `newScene` like this:

```
SKScene *newScene = [[NewScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
SKTransition *fadeOut = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:2.0];
[self.view presentScene:newScene transition:fadeOut];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, again. (: